# Calling Python member functions from C++

Tags: python, c++, linux, c++11, integration

I need to test the feasibility of calling Python member functions (running in one process)from within C++.  This is for testing interfacing C++ to an existing Python application.  I need to minimize the modifications to the Python code as that's run by a separate team.  Therefore I do not have control of when the Python objects are created on the C++ side.  For my test I'd like to try and:

1. See if I can determine how many instances of a specified Python class have been created
2. If that number is > 0, then I would like to test calling a member function on one of the instantiated Python objects from C++

I can do a simple call from C++ to a global, non member Python function, but can't figure out how to do the above 2 steps from the C++ side.

I'd also like to try and do this without pulling in the Boost Python interop. library (but will if that's the only way this can be achieved).

Thanks if anyone can advise.

Comment: "I ... cannot see how to get a reference to the created Python object from C++ who's member I need to call" - you're going to have to explain that. Why do you not have a reference to the object? Why do you need to call a method on some object you have no reference to? Imagine someone told you the same thing in C++ - they can't figure out how to call member functions in C++ because they can't figure out how to access the object they need to call a member function of.

Comment: Will add some clarification yes.

Comment: @user2357112 Is it clearer now, or more explanations required?

Comment: It's much clearer now. The next confusing part is why you're trying to do things this way. You wouldn't expect to be able to do either of these things with a C++ class without explicitly changing the class to enable it, would you?

Comment: Both "track instances of this class" functionality and "get arbitrary existing instance of this class" functionality need to be things the class provides. For the second thing, it might be better to just create your own instance, or get one from some specific system you know has an instance.

Comment: The reason I cannot simply create the classes from the C++ side is that I'm trying to interface to a complicated legacy Python application, and it currently manages all object creation, lifecycle etc.  If I start changing that, then that could be a big rabbit hole to go down.  So I need to work out how to get a pointer to an object on the Python side and call one or more of it's member functions from C++